# What is the robust way to open Gallery of Android in code?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the following currently:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent);
```

It works perfectly in most cases, but it generates the following exception at least for an Android 2.3.4 device:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://media/external/video/media }
```

Could anyone share a universal way to open Gallery on Android devices?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about opening the picture gallery, the below can be used to select an image from the SD card:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);//only local images
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_ADD);
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  I should have stated that I was referring to video files. I changed your code to use intent.setType("video/*"); It does show all the video files, but I prefer using Gallery that shows all the folders, not just a list of files.